# Developing resolution independent flex web application

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, flexbuilder

Well. I checked this link [Flex Cross Resolution Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239553/flex-cross-resolution-applications) and it did not help. Infact, the display varies from browser to browser, (for eg. chrome vs ie8) Chrome has bigger browser window. How to develop flex applications in this case ? I am using values in percentages. However, it doesnt help. A panel which displays properly in IE8, appears big in chrome with text and buttons having same size. How to solve this problem ? Giving fixed width is not a solution. Is there any other way ?

Comment: Percentage widths are generally the answer.  Maybe you should provide some screenshots / code to demonstrate your exact problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `maxWidth` & `maxHeight` properties of your buttons in concert with setting percentage based `width` & `height`.  That will ensure you're buttons (or other components) don't grow bigger than you want regardless of browser stage size.

Another option that could work is breaking your buttons up in `Group` tags.  Then make the spacing between your groups of buttons percentage-based.